# How to initialize Bootstrap script plugins on callback (Infinite Scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, infinite-scroll

I'm working on a website and everything is going great: the elements are rendering and responding to clicks and hovers as I'd like them to, courtesy of Bootplus [a derivative of Bootstrap], the elements are all being put into place correctly, courtesy of Isotope, and elements are even being put into place correctly by Isotope after pagination using Infinite Scroll, courtesy of a callback in the Infinite Scroll function.

However nothing after the first page responds entirely correctly to being clicked in the way that the first page's worth does.  (They actually do open as they should (Collapse plugin), but currently as soon as the collapsible comment toggle is selected the website scrolls down so that the toggle button clicked is barely in sight at the top.)

So how do I use a callback function [or something] so that elements loaded by Infinite Scroll behave the same as the original page's elements??????

Current Script:

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#ISCONTAINER');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.shifty-item'
  });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)',
bufferPx:900,
    itemSelector : '.shifty-item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {msgText:"Patience is a virtue.",
        finishedMsg: 'Out of new things to show you today.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
      }
    },
    // call Isotope as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
    }//SOMEWHERE HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD IN WHATEVER FUNCTION ISN'T FIRING YET TO MAKE BEHAVIOR AWESOME
  );


});
```